# Bootstrap navtabs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, datepicker

I have a bootstrap navtab that displays data in a table on each tab.  I also have a datepicker that allows you to enter a date, click submit and then show the data for that date in the tabs.  I needed to be able to switch between tabs and enter a date in a datepicker to update the data on tab click.  What I did works, except that when I initially try to switch from delayedspiff tab to instantspiff tab, instantspiff won't work until I enter a date and click submit on my button.  Here is my code for my navtabs and button:

```
<div class="row spiff-datepicksection">
                <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-offset-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                <input type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input class="spiffdate-btn spiffdate" type="button" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row spiff_tabs_body">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs spiff_tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active">

                        <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" class="spiffdate" role="tab" data-id="delayedspiff" data-toggle="tab">Potential Spiff</a>


                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation">

                        <a href="#profile" class="spiffdate" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-id="instantspiff" data-toggle="tab">Instant Spiff</a>     

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content" id="details">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="delayedspiff"></div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="instantspiff"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my click event.  I'm trying to use the class spiffdate to be able to use the click event on tab switch.

```
<script>    
    $(".spiffdate").click(function () {
       var correctId = $("ul.spiff_tabs li.active a").attr('data-id');

       var endDate = $("#startDate").val();
       if (endDate == "") {

       } else {
           if (correctId == "delayedspiff")
           {
               FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff?endDate=' + endDate, 'delayedspiff')


           } else if (correctId = "instantspiff") {
               FormGet('dashboard/instantspiff?endDate=' + endDate, 'delayedspiff')

           }           
       }     
   });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening here is that your click function is actually invoking prior to the tab change event occurring. So the `active` class hasn't been applied to the new element prior to you doing something else.

To resolve this, I would instead watch the`shown.bs.tab` event.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    //do your code here now
});
```

Comment: Hi Ohgodwhy this doesn't work, because then  my button click event doesn't work.  Is there anyway to do both the tab click and the button click in one function?

Answer (score 0):

What @Ohgodwhy recommended is the correct way to check the event on tab switch. But since you have the click handler mapped to the submit button and the tabs, you would need to handle the calls correctly.

Here's something you may try

```
var correctId;
var triggerFromTabs;

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    alert('Event From Tab');
        if($("#startDate").val().length) 
           populateData();                   
});

function populateData()
{
    alert('populate data');
    if (correctId == "delayedspiff")
           {
               $("#divData").html("Data For Delayed");             


           } else if (correctId == "instantspiff") {

               $("#divData").html("Data For Instant");

           }     
}


$(".spiffdate").click(function (e) {
       if($(this).data("id") != undefined)
       { 
           triggerFromTabs = true;
           correctId = $(this).data("id");
       }
       else
       {
           triggerFromTabs = false;
           correctId = $("ul.spiff_tabs li.active a").attr('data-id');
       }
       alert("Selected tab : " + correctId);
       if($("#startDate").val().length && !triggerFromTabs)   
         populateData();
   });
```

Here's the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/201/